# Error : The body of your post POST request is not well formed multipart/form-data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

While using IE and posting to AWS getting the below error.

Here is my ajax request

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: postingurl, //s3 bucket url
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
   //   contentType: false,   // This not worked
  //    contentType: "multipart/form-data", // This also not worked
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.responseText); // error is the title of this question
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        // Success
    });
```

Tried to remove the content type also. This working fine in Mozilla and Chrome.

Not working in IE. I am using IE 10. any pointers ?

Comment: Run Fiddler Proxy, compare a working request with the failing IE request.